# Concatenate multiple classes with SASS Ampersand (&) operator

Tags: sass

I have a function that returns a list of classes and since this function is out of context here let's assume the returned value is:

`$classes: '.class1, .class2';`

I want to generate the following CSS:

```
.main-class.class1, .main-class.class2 {
  color: white;
}
```

I tried this:

```
.main-class {
  &#{$classes} {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

But the output is:

```
.main-class.class1, .main-class. class2 {
  color: white;
}
```

I know that doing the following works:

```
.main-class {
  &.class1, &.class2 {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

however the class names `class1` and `class2` are dynamic and must come from a variable like above.

Answer (score 1):

I got it by using [`selector-append`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/selector#append) this way:

```
$classes: '.class1, .class2';

.main-class {
  @at-root #{selector-append(&, $classes)} {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

output CSS:

```
.main-class.class1, .main-class.class2 {
  color: white;
}
```